# Can I use the PyQgis QgisPluginLayer to create heatmaps?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, maps, heat-map

I am working in an application to generate maps from a bunch of MIF/MID files, I already created almost all the maps that I need, but, now I want to create heatmaps. I can't find any way of creating them with the current PyQgis API. Recently, I noticed there is something called [QgisPluginLayer](http://www.qgis.org/pyqgis-cookbook/pluginlayer.html#subclassing-qgspluginlayer). I was wondering if there is a way of using those kind of layers to create the heatmaps in PyQgis.